# Read binary file in block of 200 bytes

Tags: c++, fread

I need to read a file in blocks of 200 bytes.
So i'm using this:

```
int readData(char* data, FILE* fp){
sizeReturn=fread(data, 200, 1, fp);
cerr << sizeReturn << endl;
return sizeReturn;
}
while((size=readData(data, fp))>0)
    write(fileno(stdout), data, size);
```

I'm just trying to read the first 200 bytes, i know i need to do a fseek to advance, but i can't even read the first 200 bytes.
It returns 0 bytes read.
I need to read 200 by 200 on each loop because i'm sending it using udp, so i'm testing with a small number of bytes.
Someone can help me to read the first 200 bytes.

Thanks

Comment: I rolled back the edit because `cerr << sizeReturn << endl;` is most definitely not vaild C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved:

Just `fread(data, 1, 200, fp);`
I want to read one element with 200 bytes and not 200 elements with 1 byte

Thanks